# Unrecognized option "clients" under "liip_search"

Tags: symfony

I installed liipsearch bundle like sayed in his documentation,When i run app/console cache:clear i got this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException] Unrecognized option "clients" under "liip_search"

Can anyone explain me what to do?Thanks.
and this is my config/config.yml

```
liip_search:
clients:
    google_rest:
        api_key: '%google.api_key%'
        search_key: '%google.search_key%'
```

Comment: can you post the relevant section of the app/config/config.yml files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you Enabled the Bundle in the Kernel ?

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Liip\SearchBundle\LiipSearchBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```